# Having issues using Laravel and nginx with WPN-XM

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, wpn-xm

I installed WPN-XM in order to use nginx for a Laravel 4.2 project but only the index page work, others pages like `.../AboutMePage` don't work like

I know the Laravel configuration for nginx should look like the following .conf file but I don't know where to paste it exactely.

```
 # WPN-XM Server Stack 
 # 
 # Nginx Server Setup Example 
 # for an Application based on the Laravel Framework 
 # 
 # Do not forget to add an hosts entry for http://laravel.dev 
 # 
 server 
 { 
     listen       127.0.0.1:80; 
     root         www/laravel/public; 

     # Make site accessible from http://laravel.dev/ 
     server_name laravel.dev; 


     index   index.php index.html; 


     location / { 
         # Request Order: serve request as file, then as directory, 
         # then fall back to displaying a 404. 
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; 
     } 


     location ~ \.php$ { 
         try_files $uri /index.php =404; 
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; 
         fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9100; 
         fastcgi_index  index.php; 
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
         include fastcgi_params; 
     } 
 }
```

Comment: You say other page don't work. What is the error ? 
For your nginx conf have a look at https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/wiki/Files-and-Folders. It is written 'c:\server\bin\nginx\' as the path to nginx executables and config with 'c:\server' as default location for installation

Comment: I have an HTTP 404 error. I got the nginx.conf file but don't know if I should replace it with the above code or not... :/

Comment: Your actual config seems good for Laravel. Uncomment try_files directive in php location. You should not need it. 
You can't replace nginx.conf file by this one. Don't do it ! However you can edit nginx.conf (make a copy before) and fill the server block inside it according to the config you have here. Is your nginx.conf like the one here : https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/blob/master/configs/nginx.conf ?

Comment: seriously, I have no idea, about what you're explaining, should I replace the server bloc in the nginx.conf file with the one above?

Comment: In you nginx.conf you don't only have a server block. You have something like http { server {} }. The server block is inside the http block. So edit the first server block of nginx.conf so as to make it like the one above.

Comment: Well I did this before but it don't work, it don't even show the index page.

Comment: Assuming WPN-XM control panel show nginx and php OK, you said index.php was working with default config ? Can you provide some ngnix logs ?

Comment: Well, I reinstall WPN-XM today but still facing the same problem. The nginx log folder is emty and this is my nginx.conf file after adding the code above: https://paste.ee/p/4S3Tp

Answer (score 1):

There are few things that seems incorrect.

First you should use absolute path for root directive.
Then, you want to access the app using `http://laravel.dev/` but did you read what is written above : `# Do not forget to add an hosts entry for http://laravel.dev` So if your `server_name` directive is set to http://laravel.dev/ you will have to add `127.0.0.1 laravel.dev` to your hosts file.
Last, nginx log folder is empty because error_log is not defined.

Therefore I would recommend the following server block inside your nginx.conf

```
# WPN-XM Server Stack
#
# Nginx Server Setup Example
# for an Application based on the Laravel Framework
#
# Do not forget to add an hosts entry for http://laravel.dev
#
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    root /www/nerds/public; ## Use absolute paths for root directive

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost
    server_name localhost;

    error_log logs/error.log;

    index index.php index.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root www; ## I let it as default WPN-XM config despite what I said above
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri /index.php =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9100;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

This config assumes that :

- nerds is your laravel app folder
- public is the public directory of your laravel app.
- You access the app using http://localhost/. If you want to change this don't forget to modify hosts file and `server_name` directive.
- You'll find nginx logs in WPN-XM control panel

Comment: Hello, Well I finally made it work using this Nginx.conf file https://paste.ee/p/0HvLw . Now I am facing another problem that may require another post, that is how can others Laravel projects? should I add new root path for each project with its virtual host name or?

Comment: Pretty same thing as above. Note that you don't use absolute root path.
For Laravel, you should add a new server block with new root path and different server_name (or port but I'm not sure it's recommended).